# C#: How to enter a specific name into a program to continue and how to make a loop?

Tags: c#, console-application

In the beginning, I would like to have the user enter the word "Formula" into the program in order to continue. If anything else is entered, it will say "Wrong name. Try again." and it will ask the user to enter the name again.

At the end, when the program asks if the user wants to try again, if the user enters "Yes" then the program would start from the beginning again. If the user enters "No" then it would exit the program.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication_program
{
    class formula
    {
        internal double numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree;
        internal double formulaResult()
        {
            return (6 * numberOne * numberTwo) + (6 * numberTwo * numberThree) + (6 * numberThree * numberOne);
        }
        internal double formulaResultTwo()
        {
            return formulaResult() * 0.9;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            formula integer = new formula();

            string name;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            //Enter the word "Formula" to start calculating.
            //If anything else is entered then it will say "Wrong name. Try again."

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
            integer.numberOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number");
            integer.numberTwo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the third number");
            integer.numberThree = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("The first result is {0}", integer.formulaResult());
            Console.WriteLine("The second result is {0}", integer.formulaResultTwo());

            Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to try again?");
            //Enter "Yes" to try again or enter "No" to exit. 

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Lesson 4: Control Statements - Loops](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson04)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a loop.  I would recomend a do ... while loop.

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    //Rest of your code here.
    Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to try again?");
}
while(!Console.ReadLine().Equals("No"));
```

As long as the entered value is not No, then the loop will start over and the user will be asked to enter their name again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into [while loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) and [if statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

You might also want to look at the [break statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) to interrupt loops